# How to implement - (void)complete:(id)sender?

Tags: objective-c, autocomplete

I am trying to override NSTextView `- (void)complete:(id)sender` method but I can't find any example on how to do it. What does this method do? There are examples, or where I can find the original implementation?

Thank you!

—Alberto

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's all there in the documentation of `complete:`

> #### Discussion
>
> …
>
> The delegate may replace or modify the
>   list of possible completions by
>   implementing
>   [`textView:completions:forPartialWordRange:indexOfSelectedItem:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSTextViewDelegate/textView:completions:forPartialWordRange:indexOfSelectedItem:).
>   Subclasses may control the list by
>   overriding
>   [`completionsForPartialWordRange:indexOfSelectedItem:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTextView/completionsForPartialWordRange:indexOfSelectedItem:).

Normally, one doesn't *need* to reimplement `complete:`.

Answer (score 4):

Also checkout the [SearchField](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/SearchField/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004112) example, especially the [implementation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/SearchField/listing3.html).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should try to do your *thing* in the delegate with below method instead.

```
- (NSArray *)textView:(NSTextView *)textView 
          completions:(NSArray *)words 
  forPartialWordRange:(NSRange)charRange 
  indexOfSelectedItem:(NSInteger *)index
```

One rarely need to subclass in Cocoa. When thinking about it check the delegate methods again.